# Ordnance Survey Maps in .osm.pbf format

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, ordnance-survey

I see that you can download Ordnance Survey maps as `ESRI Shape files`, so I would like to take those and convert them into a `.osm.pbf` file so that I can more easily use them.

Are there any tools out there that do this? Or, sources of Ordnance Survey .osm.pbf files?

Comment: Pbf is mostly a data transfer format and seldom used directly except in vector tiles. Usually people make conversion FROM pbf into other formats with ogr2pgsql etc. What is your use case?

Comment: Thanks. I realize what .pbf files are for. I use `libosmscout` to convert .osm.pbf files into different usable formats for quick viewing. And, since it only supports osm.pbf files, I wanted to see if there was a way to get Ordnance Survey files into that so I could convert them.

Comment: So you want to convert Ordnance Survey shape files into OpenStreetMap pbf files just so you can convert them into some other format? If you tell us what the "different usable formats" are maybe there's a direct way of converting the Ordnance Survey shapes to that.

Comment: @Spacedman - The "different usable formats" are the database and index files that `libosmscout` creates. They are specific to that tool, so that is why I am needing them to be in .osm.pbf because I use `libosmscout` in my projects.

Comment: Have you tried the "conversion tools" listed here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software_comparison/Import_a_shapefile

Comment: Theres no logic in what you saying..

Comment: @Balazs Why? Maybe you don't understand my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the OSM wiki about [Shapefiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles) and [Converting_map_data_between_formats](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_map_data_between_formats) to get all known tools for converting shapefiles into raw OSM XML format or compressed binary PBF files.

Comment: You are seeing an option to convert to compressed binary PBF? I am not seeing that.

Comment: Indeed ... on the last mentioned wiki page there is no link to the often used and popular http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert ... this tool should do the job.

Comment: But it doesn't look like you can convert from ESRI Shape files.

Comment: So you are looking for a tool that convers shapefiles directly to osm.pbf format? If yes, and there is not tool available for this, you can consider two  ways: use raw osm.xml format as a between file format, or find out whether libosmscout can use osm.xml files next to compressd osm.pbf files. Success?

Comment: Correct. I need to convert shape files to osm.pbf.